# How to generate an ID which is valid for 15 seconds in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to generate a unique ID for cloud Firebase or any other plugin in flutter. I need help in creating a function that generates an ID every 15 seconds and would be the same for all users that generate the ID at a given time.

E.g.

1. User A and B generate an ID at the same time, the returned ID is ABCD.
2. User A generates an ID, gets ID ABCD as a result.User B within 15 seconds tries to generate an ID and gets ABCD as the result.But,User B generates an ID 15 seconds later, gets EFGH as a result.

Comment: If you are talking about users, then I expect this to be server side, not client side. If so, are you using Firebase specifically or was it just a suggestion. Can you please clarify a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: What are the purpose of this ID's? Is it some kind of security feature? In that case, each device needs to contain the secret which are needed to combine with time to generate the ID.

Comment: @João Soares I am just trying to implement an app where in which people are trying to call each other randomly in a time span of 15 seconds. No it is just I thought like that ,there was no suggestions as such.Hope it answers your question as well @ julemand101

Comment: I don't understand the use but if that's what you want, you can have a field in the database that will hold this generated ID and run a cron job to update the ID every 15 sec.In this way, all the users will be getting same id at a given time as they are reading it from database.

Comment: @ Shubham Gupta thanks.I will try and let you know

Comment: If the suggestion above is an option, then you could just use Redis to manage that. It would take care of automatically deleting the ids after X amount of time. https://redis.io/commands/expire

Comment: @ João Soares ,thanks I will try that too